# "In term of" vs "in the term of"

Tags: grammar

Please, can somebody explain which one is correct in this case:

> Subjects' performance was analysed in ***the*** terms of accuracy and stability...

or

> Subjects' performance was analysed in terms of accuracy and stability...

Comment: No definite article: "... was analysed in terms of...."

Answer (score 1):

consider the idiom **in terms of (something)**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+terms+of+(something))

> 1. As measured with a certain type of unit or category.
> 2. Regarding; in reference to.

As in:

> We track our shipments **in terms of** weight, rather than individual
>   units. The tragedy caused billions in damage, but the biggest losses
>   were **in terms of** lives.